# Calculate percentage between two numbers?

Tags: php, laravel

I have these two numbers original one is `1000` the new one is `440`

I need to calculate the percentage between them as follow:

```
1000 
440

The percentage that getting is 44% and left is 56%
```

my helper function:

```
function calculatePercentage($original, $given)
{
    $percentChange = (($original - $given) / $original) * 100;

    return round(abs($percentChange)) . '%';
}
```

This gives me the reset percentage!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
    function calculatePercentage($original, $given)
    {
        $percentageOfGiven = round(abs( ($given * 100) / $original ));

        return [
            'getting' => $percentageOfGiven . '%',
            'left' => (100 - $percentageOfGiven) . '%'
        ];
    }
```

The output will be like `[ 'getting' => "44%", 'left' => "56%"]` .

The principle used is that if the original is 100% then what would be the given value.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be like

```
function calculatePercentage($original, $given)
{
    $percentChange = ($given / $original) * 100;

    return round(abs($percentChange)) . '%';
}
```

If I am wrong, I probably didn't understand ques enough

Comment: that gives me `227%`!